# Playwright - do while selector not found on page

Tags: automated-tests, playwright

I am using PlayWright and want to perform an operation whilst an element is not found in the DOM.

My code looks similar to:

```
while(!page.locator('.list-empty'))
 {
   await removeAllRoles();
 }
```

this doesnt work. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `isVisible` method for that.

```js
while(!(await page.locator('.list-empty').isVisible())) {
  // do something
}
```

Also, you can use `isHidden` method. It's the opposite of `isVisible`.

```js
while(await page.locator('.list-empty').isHidden()) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: is there a way to add a timeout also?
i want to //do something with a slight delay as asynchronous call...